# BeautifulSoup - Adding attributes on Resultset

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's my html structure to scrape:

```
<div class='schedule-lists'>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                    <ul class='showtime-lists'>
                        <li>...</li>
                            <li><a auditype="N" cinema="0100" href="javascript:void(0);" >12:45</a></li>
                        <li>...</li>  -- (same structured as above)
                        <li>...</li>  -- (same structured as above)

        <li>...</li> -- (same structured as above)
        <li>...</li> -- (same structured as above)
```

Here's my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = get('www.example.com')
response_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
containers = response_html.find_all('ul', class_='showtime-lists')
#print(containers)
[<ul class="showtime-lists">
<li><a auditype="N" cinema="0100" href="javascript:void(0);" >12:45</a></li>
```

How can i add attributes on my Resultset containers? like adding movietitle="Logan" so it become:

```
<li><a movietitle="Logan" auditype="N" cinema="0100" href="javascript:void(0);" >12:45</a></li>
```

My best trial is using .append method but it can be done because the ResultSet act like a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
...
a = find_all('a')
i = 0
for tag in a:
    a[i]['movietitle'] = 'Logan'
    i += 1
print str(a)
```